# Is it possible to create Windows PowerShell Cmdlets with F#?

Tags: powershell, f#

Reading the Microsoft documentation for creating PowerShell Cmdlets, I notice there is no example code for F#; instead, there is a message saying that "This language is not supported or no code example is available.".

Is F# not supported for creating Cmdlets, or aren't there any examples in F#?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Take a look at this:
[Writing PowerShell Cmdlets in F#](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2009/08/writing-powershell-cmdlets-in-f-may-ctp.html).  Not exactly a complete example of how to do this but it certainly seems to be possible to write cmdlets in F#.

EDIT:
There is a more extensive example [here](http://stevegilham.blogspot.com/2008/12/writing-powershell-cmdlets-in-f.html) but the contextual information is a little bit out of date.  Actually the contextual information is a bit out of date on both links but the first link is more recent.

Comment: is absolutely right. It is possible. I created a few cmdlets in F# and did not find it much different from doing this in C# (except syntax, indeed, and the fact that *actual* job is implemented in F# which is better sometimes).